# Taking data from TimePicker android

Tags: android, mobile

I am trying to make a very simple app. I just need to take in a time from a TimePicker element and add to it 30 minute increments based on a Spinner with values 1-8. Namely, if the users selects the value '3' and the time '8:30am' the program should do

```
 (30min) * 3 = 90min
```

then

```
 (8:30am) + 90min = 10:00am
```

Does anyone know how to take input from a Spinner (the values 1-8), do a simple calculation, and then add it to data input from a TimePicker?

Any help on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple things:
1. Setting up a listener to get the value selected from the picker and then grabbing the values of the time picker:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    Integer[] numbers = new Integer[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};


        final TimePicker tp = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
        tp.setIs24HourView(true);
        Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, numbers);

s1.setAdapter(adapter);
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){   
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)

            {
                int index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
                switch(index)
                {
                case 0: 
                    int min = tp.getCurrentMinute();
                    int hour = tp.getCurrentHour();
                    //Do your calculations here etc

                }
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {


            }
        });
```

}

1. This might be helpful for you too, how to setup listener for timepicker, (if someone could help me out and edit this, cant get it to format correctly):

   ```
   final TimePicker tp = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
           TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener listen = new  

           TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {

       public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           //do some calculations with hourOfDay and minute

       }
   };
   ```

   tp.setOnTimeChangedListener(listen);